# OpenCV + Qt + cv::mat::deallocate and cv::fastFree(void *) memory problems

Tags: qt, opencv

I've got two error messages:

> cv::mat::deallocate
>   cv::fastFree(void *)

While I was trying to compile my OpenCV and QT project. I am fighting with this problem for fifth day. Please guys if you know how I can solve this problem, write it here.

PS: I've uploaded an image.

http://postimg.org/image/wsyq8daf5/

Answer (score 0):

After this day, my problem with the camera was totally solved.There are no more problems.Now i will continue my GUI project thanks to all of you guys.After 1-2 months i will start searching for how to write printer driver ;), but however.Thanks too all again. ;)

Finally i solved my problem using the QCamera class.Well guys, use QCamera, you don't need anything else to capture videos or images.Read everything about it and bye bye ;)